# Как привязать данные к DataGrid из разных классов WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

я создал два класса с данными:

```
public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

И второй класс

```
public class Person1
    {
       public string SecondName { get; set; }
    }
```

Далее в MainWindow я добавил: правильно или нет не могу понять

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<Person> person;
    private ObservableCollection<Person1> person1;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        person = new ObservableCollection<Person>()
        {
            new Person(){Name="Анатолий"},
            new Person(){Name="Василий"}
        };
        DGR.ItemsSource = person;

        person1 = new ObservableCollection<Person1>()
        {
            new Person1(){SecondName="Федоров"},
            new Person1(){SecondName="Петров"}
        };
        DGR.ItemsSource = person1;
    }
}
```

}
Ну и соответственно я создаю DataGrid

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DGR" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="171" Width="497">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Имя" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Фамилия" Binding="{Binding SecondName}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Я понимаю что что-то неправильно делаю, но никак не могу с этим справиться, получается, что в DataGrid виден только один Класс с данными, либо Person, либо Person1.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а какой смысл существования двух таких классов?

Comment: Ранее мною был задан вопрос, на него не смогли пока что ответить https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/836407/binding-datagrid-wpf, либо я неправильно написал вопрос, мне надо нумерацию вставить в таблицу, но непросто нумерация, а так чтобы она при удалении могла восстанавливать порядок чисел(нумерации). Так мне пришлось выходы искать, но пока что только так я пробую.

Comment: иииииииииии что?

Comment: А что значит: `...чтобы она при удалении могла восстанавливать порядок чисел(нумерации`. Были люди `1,2,3,4,5`, удалили `3` и тогда `4` стал `3`, а `5` стал `4`, так что ли?

Comment: Да, абсолютно верно.

Comment: Сейчас попробую написать пример.

Comment: Спасибо большое, а то уже ум за ум заходит:)))

Comment: [Здесь можно скачать пример](https://yadi.sk/d/n4QXMm7k3XBZjR)

Comment: @Bulson а что не ответом?

Comment: @tym32167 потому что пример не про байдинг двух разных классов к одному DataGrid, а про изменение нумерации в списке при удалении одного из элементов.

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду пробовать.

Comment: Для нумерации строк надо использовать конвертер: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/777851/218063

Answer (score 1):

Ваша задача выглядит странно и, в общем-то, вы никогда не должны так делать, но она решаема. Хотите вы или нет, а совместить два класса в один, пусть хотя бы анонимный, все равно придется:

```
person = new ObservableCollection<Person>()
{
    new Person(){Name="Анатолий"},
    new Person(){Name="Василий"}
};

person1 = new ObservableCollection<Person1>()
{
    new Person1(){SecondName="Федоров"},
    new Person1(){SecondName="Петров"}
};

DGR.ItemsSource = person.Zip(person1, (p, p1) => new { Person = p, Person1 = p1 });
```

В разметке надо будет указать к какому именно объекту принадлежит то или иное свойство:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Имя" Binding="{Binding Person.Name}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Фамилия" Binding="{Binding Person1.SecondName}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Если основная ваша задача — прикрутить нумерацию строк к таблице (при этом номер строки не является свойством модели), то вам нужно просто взять конвертер из этого топика: [Нумерация строк в dataGrid wpf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/777851/218063)

Comment: Спасибо Вам за помощь, у меня есть готовое решение и вот в нём как раз таки есть вариант нумерации строк, но ситуация в том что, мне нумерацию, каким то образом надо подключить к набору данных к таблице DataSet, т.к. ещё происходит сохранение самой таблицы,  но получается так, сама нумерация проходит через класс, а таблица через Набор Данных (DataSet, которая не требует наличия соединения ) и вот как совместить это никак не получается, вот и рассматривал один из вариантов, как попробовать совместить два класса.

Comment: Вы вариант с конвертером пробовали?

Comment: Да пробовал, всё нормально именно с нумерацией, вот как вы и показывали в примере, она работает, там не важно как либо через класс даже через Набор Данных, но как только я добавляю дополнительный код, допустим чтобы таблица сохранялась при закрытии, ну и открывалась уже с новыми данными, то вот здесь как раз таки и происходит сбой. Т.е. добавил новую строку с данными все нормально, добавляется следующий номер, но когда удаляешь строку, допустим где-то из середины, вот тогда нумерация сбивается, да она восстанавливается, после того когда заново программу запускаешь.

Comment: Суть такая.. 1. Данные в Наборе Данных DataSet, 2. Нумерация в таблице DataGrid (DataSet),если удаляешь строку с данными из таблицы, то нумерация должна восстановится в последовательности, 3. Сохранить данные при закрытии таблицы, всё это у меня делается но по раздельности, вместе никак:)))))

Answer (score 0):

Для отображения элементов класса добавьте в `DataGrid` свойство `ItemSource` и укажите вашу коллекцию. После в `DataGridTextColumn` привязывайте нужные поля.

Насколько мне известно, нельзя привязывать данные из разных классов в один `DataGrid`. Как вариант, вы можете создать в классе `Ptrson` поле с типом `Person1` и при привязке обращаться к нему.