# DataGrid CanUserAddRows заменить на свой

Tags: c#, wpf

По умолчанию в гриде есть CanUserAddRows. Можно ее заменить на свою? Хочу в последнюю строку кинуть кнопку добавить и по ней чтоб происходило добавление. Я изменил колонку и запихнул в неё textbox и кнопку сохранить для редактирования. А в последней хочу сделать строку для добавления записей. Можно как то это реализовать?!

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Департамент" Width="*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="Сохранить" Margin="2"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding DepartamentName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="2"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Обязательно в последней строчке? Отдельно от грида не подходит что ли?

Comment: Много элементов на форме, да и дополнительные формы и всплывающие окна для это делать не хочется(1-2 поля в гриде), хотелось бы сделать редактирование, удаление и добавление в гриде.

Comment: А чем стандартное поведение не устраивает?

Comment: А как стандартное добавление сделать в пределах mvvm?!

Comment: А при чем тут MVVM? DataGrid нормально же добавляет элементы в привязанную коллекцию. Просто привязывайте ObservableCollection и всё

Comment: Не совсем, он id = 0 ставит, + в базу надо загнать.

Comment: Вот так и пишите, что на добавление надо навесить еще дополнительные действия. Но тут тоже есть решение — подпишитесь в VM на ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged :)

Comment: Я подписался, но у меня приходят пустые значения при добавлении... А редактирование вообще не отрабатывает... Делаю по https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/4.13.php   Может из за того что я использую DataGridTemplateColumn?

Comment: Ну на самом деле я бы не лез в базу на каждый чих, на вашем месте я бы сделал одну кнопку сохранить во всем окне, по которой сохранять сразу все изменения, преимущества этого подхода — можно ничего не сохранять и тем самым будет поддержка отмены внесения изменений у вас.

Comment: Но вопрос (добавить кнопку вместо последней строки) сам по себе интересный и я начал писать решение, я вернусь с обеда, доделаю его и оформлю тогда. Ждите :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделать это можно, нужно вычленить нужную строку и дать ей свой шаблон. Как выясняется в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/778545/218063), у пустой строки внизу таблицы, которая используется для добавления новых строк, установлен специфичный `DataContext`.

Я написал такой простой `DataTemplateSelector`:

```
class DataGridRowTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var fe = (FrameworkElement)container;
        if (item?.GetType().FullName == "MS.Internal.NamedObject")
            return fe.FindResource("AdditionalRowTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        return fe.FindResource("StandartTemplate") as DataTemplate; 
    }
}
```

Т.е. нам потребуется 2 шаблона, один для обычных строк и один для последней, давайте их создадим. Кликните правой кнопкой по `DataGrid` в дизайнере Visual Studio и выберите <kbd>Edit Additional Templates</kbd><kbd>Edit RowStyle</kbd><kbd>Edit a Copy...</kbd>, введите наименование ключа и нажмите <kbd>OK</kbd>

В добавившемся стиле найдите установку шаблона контрола, у меня она выглядит так:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Border x:Name="DGR_Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
            <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1" ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
            <DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding AreRowDetailsFrozen, ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}"/>
            <DataGridRowHeader Grid.RowSpan="2" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
        </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Это и есть стандартный шаблон, надо перенести его в ресурсы, но тут есть нюанс – привязка `TemplateBinding` из ресурсов работать не умеет, поэтому все такие привязки надо заменить на `Binding ..., RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}`

Создаем в `ControlTemplate`:

```
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>

    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
```

Добавляем туда экземпляр нашего селектора:

```
        <c:DataGridRowTemplateSelector x:Key="selector"/>
```

и переносим тот наш шаблон для строки `DataGrid`:

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="StandartTemplate">
            <Border x:Name="DGR_Border" BorderBrush="{Binding BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}" BorderThickness="{Binding BorderThickness, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}" Background="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                    <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                    <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1" ItemsPanel="{Binding ItemsPanel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    <!--Почему-то эта строка не хочет работать - роняет приложение со StackoverflowException, если вы не используете строки с деталями, то вам она в общем-то не нужна-->
                    <!--<DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding AreRowDetailsFrozen, ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Visibility="{Binding DetailsVisibility, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}"/>-->
                    <DataGridRowHeader Grid.RowSpan="2" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Добавляем теперь шаблон для нижней строки:

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="AdditionalRowTemplate">
            <Button Content="Add"/>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Ну и вместо старого шаблона контрола вставляем `ContentControl` с указанием ему нужного селектора:

```
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource selector}"/>
```

На этом этапе можно запустить приложение и убедиться, что вместо пустой строки внизу отображается кнопка Add:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Осталось заставить ее работать так как вам нужно. Раз у вас MVVM, то лучшее решение — предоставить DataGrid команду, добавим Attached Property:

```
static class DataGridEx
{
    public static ICommand GetAddCommand(DataGrid obj)
        => (ICommand)obj.GetValue(AddCommandProperty);

    public static void SetAddCommand(DataGrid obj, ICommand value)
        => obj.SetValue(AddCommandProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AddCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AddCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(DataGridEx), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

Теперь можно в шаблоне с кнопкой (`AdditionalRowTemplate`) написать:

```
            <Button Content="Add" Command="{Binding (c:DataGridEx.AddCommand), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
```

Всё! Указываем в разметке `DataGrid` нужную команду и пользуемся:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" RowStyle="{DynamicResource MyDataGridRowStyle}"
          c:DataGridEx.AddCommand="{Binding AddCommand}"
```