# При сортировке в DataGrid сбивается нумерация строк WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, сортировка, datagrid

При сортировке и группировке нумерация строк в таблице DataGrid сбивается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="DGR" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding AllEmployee}" Margin="0,0,0,10">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ID" Binding="{Binding id}" Header="№"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Position" Binding="{Binding position}" Header="Фамилия"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Unit" Binding="{Binding unit}" Header="Группа"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="GroupItem">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                        <StackPanel>
                                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black" FontSize="12" 
                                                           TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                                            <TextBlock Foreground="Blue" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold"
                                                       Text="{Binding ItemCount, 
                                                    StringFormat=Количество сотрудников в группе: {0}}" Margin="30,0,0,5" />
                                            <ItemsPresenter/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>

 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ICollectionView cvTasks = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(DGR.ItemsSource);
            if(cvTasks != null && cvTasks.CanGroup == true)
            {
                cvTasks.GroupDescriptions.Clear();
                cvTasks.SortDescriptions.Clear();
                cvTasks.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("unit"));
                cvTasks.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("unit", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
            }
        }


    }

public class MainViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Employee> AllEmployee { get; set; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            this.Initialize();
        }
        private void Initialize()
        {
            AllEmployee = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
            AllEmployee.CollectionChanged += OnGroceryListChanged;
        }
        void OnGroceryListChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            NumberService.SetCollection(this.AllEmployee);
        }

    }
}

public class Employee : ViewModelBase
    {
        private int ID { get; set; }
        private string Position { get; set; }
        private string Unit { get; set; }

        public int id
        {
            get { return this.ID; }
            set
            {
                if (value != ID)
                {
                    ID = value;
                    RaisePropertyChangedEvent("id");

                }
            }
        }
        public string position
        {
            get { return Position; }
            set
            {
                if (value != Position)
                {
                    Position = value;
                    RaisePropertyChangedEvent("position");
                }
            }
        }
        public string unit
        {
            get { return Unit; }
            set
            {
                if (value != Unit)
                {
                    Unit = value;
                    RaisePropertyChangedEvent("unit");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



public static class NumberService
    {
        public static ObservableCollection<T> SetCollection<T>(ObservableCollection<T>
           targetCollection) where T : Employee
        {

            var Number = 1;


            foreach (Employee sequencedObject in targetCollection)
            {
                sequencedObject.id = Number;
                Number++;

            }

            return targetCollection;

        }
    }
}

 public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void RaisePropertyChangedEvent([CallerMemberName] 
            String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
                PropertyChanged(this, e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Спасибо, если окажете помощь в данной проблеме.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду? Вроде какие были номера у записей — те и остаются. Или вас нужно другое поведение?

Comment: Вы уж определитесь с тем, что вам нужно. Если вы делаете привязку к `Id`, то это именно Id в коллекции, ну а если вам нужен порядковый номер в отсортированной по какому-то правилу подколлекции, то и делайте привязку к этому вычисляемому на ходу параметру.

Comment: В gif я указал, группу например №1, №2 и т.д. а порядок нумерации когда данные распределились по группам, получился в разнобой, а не по порядку т.е. 1,2,3,4 и т.д. привязку группировки я сделал к столбцу "Группа"   cvTasks.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("unit")); а вот как чтобы нумерация после группировки установилась в последовательности у меня не получается.

Comment: `<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ID" Binding="{Binding id}" Header="№"/>` - что вы написали, то и происходит же. Или вы хотите, чтобы при любой операции менялся и ID сущности?

Comment: Если вам нужен просто порядковый номер, то почему не пользуетесь своим же конвертером: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/777851/218063 ?

Comment: Я его пробовал, рядом в колонку ставил и смотрел различия, так вот этот конвертер работает, но когда допустим удаляешь от куда нибудь из середины строку, то после удаления порядок чисел не выравнивается а получается как бы (1,2,3,5) грубо говоря я удалял 4 строку, а тот который у меня сейчас класс стоит он выравнивает порядковые номера, но соответственно по сортировку не подходит.

Comment: Единственно на что обратил внимание, то когда если сохраняешь в файл допустим в xml, то в этом файле порядковые номера сохранены. Т.е. находятся по порядку.

Comment: Ага, ну конвертер-то легко исправить, чтобы он пересчитывал при удалении строк. Если зададите отдельным вопросом - напишу решение.

Comment: А в том виде что у вас сейчас, вам придется при любом изменении группы в любой сущности пересчитывать номера строк для всех сущностей, да и сделать это будет не совсем просто, думаю.

Comment: Хорошо сейчас задам вопрос.